# How should I interpret the present perfect in "In no society has nonmarital childbirth been the cultural norm"?

Tags: meaning, present-perfect

The following is a sentence from *Families Without Fathers* by David Popenoe.

> In no society has nonmarital childbirth been the cultural norm.

It should mean

> there hasn't been a society where nonmarital childbirth was the cultural norm in any period in its history.

But, if the present perfect "**has been the cultural norm**" is taken as an expression of a state, it seems to mean that

> it is possible there was a society where nonmarital childbirth was the cultural norm for a limited time in its history.

What is the correct interpretation?

Answer (score 6):

The correct interpretation is that

> In no society has nonmarital childbirth been the cultural norm

is the **negation** of

> Nonmarital childbirth has been the cultural norm in some society.

This means your first interpretation is correct and the second wrong.

Comment: Then, is my second interpretation also correct?

Comment: One could hit a lot of different meaning possibilities by inserting adverbial modifiers, such as *ever* for OP's first interpretation, *long* for the second, or *till now* for the doomsday warning that the author is presumably leading up to; but bare of such modifiers the first interpretation stands.

Comment: Can't "Nonmarital childbirth has been the cultural norm in some society" mean 
the continuation of existense of the culture which considers nonmarital childbirth as norm 
from an unspecified time up to now in some society? If it can, 
isn't the negation of the continuation of existense not the negation of the existense but
the negation of the continuation?

Comment: Good answer, i'd just note that the obvious factual incorrectness of the content of the sentence contributes to the confusion about its grammatical structure.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 is correct, and I don't think option 2 is a possible interpretation of the sentence. However, it would have been better to say, "Nonmarital childbirth has not been the cultural norm in any society" or "There has not been a society in which nonmarital childbirth has been the cultural norm." The use of *no* as equivalent to the German *kein* (as here) generally calls for a re-write.

Answer (score -1):

Statements such as these are usually more confusing than helpful when trying to understand what "proper English" prescribes and proscribes. These kinds of statements are written in such a way to sound definitive, when they are actually more opinion than fact. As such, it becomes an endless exercise to specify the *exact* meaning.

Does it sound like "native English"? Yes. What is the intended meaning? That would be most definitely the first interpretation you've offered, not the second.